# web.config with multiple impersonation

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

My applications use data from one SQL server on our network.  The SQL server is on separate machine from the IIS server that hosts my applications.  I am using integrated security, Windows authentication, and impersonation in the web.config. Now I need to connect to another SQL box that does work with the impersonated account.  So how do I pass proper identity to each of the SQL servers to get data from each?  The web.config only allows one impersonation.